# Automapper EF6 mapping nested entities with complex primary key (2 columns)

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I'm kinda new to Automapper and I've been struggling with this for a couple days, I'd really appreciate any help solving this. Also I've been trying to find some post that would help me but I can't find any similar situation.

I have this main entity:

```
public partial class cht_cotizacion
{
    public cht_cotizacion()
    {
        this.cht_cotizacion_opcion = new List<cht_cotizacion_opcion>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LocaleId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> EstatusId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual cht_cat_estatus cht_cat_estatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<cht_cotizacion_opcion> cht_cotizacion_opcion { get; set; }
}
```

Related entity cht_cat_estatus:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class cht_cat_estatus
{
    public cht_cat_estatus()
    {
        this.cht_cotizacion = new List<cht_cotizacion>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LocaleId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<cht_cotizacion> cht_cotizacion { get; set; }
}
```

Related entity cht_cotizacion_opcion:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class cht_cotizacion_opcion
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LocaleId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long CotizacionId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int TipoOpcionId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public System.DateTime FechaOpcion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual cht_cotizacion cht_cotizacion { get; set; }
}
```

Entity cht_cat_status has a complex primary key composed by: **"Id"** and **"LocaleId"**, and they are foreign on cht_cotizacion on columns: **"EstatusId"** and **"LocaleId"**.

DTO Classes:

```
[DataContract()]
public partial class cht_cotizacionDTO
{
    public cht_cotizacionDTO()
    {
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String LocaleId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public Nullable<Int32> EstatusId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public List<cht_cat_estatusDTO> cht_cat_estatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public List<cht_cotizacion_opcionDTO> cht_cotizacion_opcion { get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
public partial class cht_cotizacion_opcionDTO
{
    public cht_cotizacion_opcionDTO()
    {
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String LocaleId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public Int64 CotizacionId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public Int32 TipoOpcionId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public DateTime FechaOpcion { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public Int64 cht_cotizacion_Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
public partial class cht_cat_estatusDTO
{
    public cht_cat_estatusDTO()
    {
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String LocaleId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public String Descripcion { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public List<Int64> cht_cotizacion_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then the usage (this works perfectly):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<cht_cotizacion, cht_cotizacionDTO>()
    //cfg.CreateMap<cht_cat_estatus, cht_cat_estatusDTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<cht_cotizacion_opcion, cht_cotizacion_opcionDTO>();
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var source = cotizacion;
cotizacionDTO = mapper.Map<cht_cotizacion, cht_cotizacionDTO>(source);
```

But as soon as I include the other related entity:

```
cfg.CreateMap<cht_cat_estatus, cht_cat_estatusDTO>();
```

Even using:

```
cfg.CreateMap<cht_cotizacion, cht_cotizacionDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.cht_cat_estatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.cht_cat_estatus));
```

I end up getting the error:

```
{"Error mapping types.
    Mapping types:
        cht_cotizacion -> cht_cotizacionDTO
        cht_cotizacion -> cht_cotizacionDTO
    Type Map configuration:
        cht_cotizacion -> cht_cotizacionDTO
        cht_cotizacion -> cht_cotizacionDTO
    Property:
        cht_cat_estatus"
}
```

Comment: Could you please first do us (and yourself) a favor and remove these useless prefixes? They make the code unnecessarily hard to read. Also, it's strongly recommended to use standard naming conventions, like CamelCase class and property names, plural names for collections, and singular names for scalar properties and references. This is esp. important when using a name-convention driven tool like AutoMapper. Chances are that while doing this, you'll see why AutoMapper is having trouble resolving the name mappings. I suspect that it tries to execute *flattening* where it's impossible to do that.

Comment: Sure @GertArnold, I totally get your point, sadly for me this is an existing project and they decided to use that kind of name convention if it can be called that way. For the sake of the testing purpose I'll try to change all the models name convention to something more useful, but right now I need some hints on how to map entities with complex primary keys with Automapper, if possible at all.

Comment: OK, that's life. Also note that AutoMapper is not aware of any primary key concept in your class model. It just tries to map matching names and explicit mapping specifications.